# print multiple set of numbers from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
function numbersInBucket(setOfNumbers, numbersInArray) {
 var numbers = [];
 for (var i = numbersInArray; i > 0; i--){
  numbers.push(i);
 }
 numbers.sort(function(){
  return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5);
  }
 );
 return numbers.slice(0, setOfNumbers).sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
}


function print(numbers){
 var html = "";
   for (var i in numbers) {
     html = html + '<li class="item">' + numbers[i] + '</li>';
   }
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
} 

function rowOfNumbers(){
 for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  print(numbersInBucket(5, 75));
 }
}
```

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center;
  }
  ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .item {
    border: 5px solid #E7F7F5;
    color: #E7F7F5;
    margin: 20px;  
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 220%;
   justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="output"></ul>
</div>
<input class="button" type="button" value="click " id="reload" onclick="rowOfNumbers()">
```

Hello there;
How can I print multiple set of numbers. For example, 
3 12 23 33 44, 2 5 13 22 36, 12 23 27 29 44. With my current code I can have one set of numbers as output the way I want it. But I would like multiple sets with different numbers. I try using a for loop with no luck. The set of numbers has to be inside an li tag. Can someone please set me in the right direction, I am trying to learn interactive web development.

Answer (score 0):

On this line: `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;` you are replacing the inner HTML of the element with a new set of elements. This means that you are emptying the element before appending newly generated elements, so they never increase in number.

A quick solution will be instead of overwriting the inner HTML, you append to it using: `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += html;`.

See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
function numbersInBucket(setOfNumbers, numbersInArray) {
 var numbers = [];
 for (var i = numbersInArray; i > 0; i--){
  numbers.push(i);
 }
 numbers.sort(function(){
  return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5);
  }
 );
 return numbers.slice(0, setOfNumbers).sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
}


function print(numbers){
 var html = "";
   for (var i in numbers) {
     html = html + '<li class="item">' + numbers[i] + '</li>';
   }
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += html;
} 

function rowOfNumbers(){
 for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  print(numbersInBucket(5, 75));
 }
}
```

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center;
  }
  ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .item {
    border: 5px solid #E7F7F5;
    color: #E7F7F5;
    margin: 20px;  
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 220%;
   justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="output"></ul>
</div>
<input class="button" type="button" value="click " id="reload" onclick="rowOfNumbers()">
```